# Forms authentication in lightswitch vs2012

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-lightswitch

I am trying to implement forms authentication in lightswitch (vs2012) but I cannot get a  login page to display.  I don't need any complex roles, I am just trying to setup a single user account that has access to the entire application.   I have used a tutorial that was put up by [Edu Lorenzo](http://edulorenzo.wordpress.com/2011/03/04/adding-forms-authentication-based-access-control-to-a-visual-studio-lightswitch-application/) but it didn't work out.  Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You won't see the login form while you're debugging your project. You'll only see it in the **published** version of your application.

The logical question that you might then ask, is "how do I debug my permissions?". When you add a permission, over on the right-hand side of the row is a checkbox called "Grant For Debug". When you want to simulate being in a role that has that permissions, you tick the box. For simulating not having the permissions, you untick it.

But you mention that you want a "single user that has access to the entire application". But since you're asking about the login form, I can only assume that you still want him to log in, so that not everyone can access the application, yes?

If the only reason you want authentication is so that just that only *one* user can log in, simply add him to the *Administration* role (in case he ever needs to add another *user*, or add *roles*), in the **published** application. In your code you won't be testing for any specific permissions, so that should give you what you want.

Comment: Awesome, I will give this a shot when I get a chance in a couple of days.  I tried to publish it with forms auth already but I will give it another try because I may not have tried hard enough...

Comment: Make sure that you specify an administrator account when you publish, or or nobody will be able to log in, or add users/roles.